# Understanding mutate function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am given a snippet of R code which reads as below -

```
library(dplyr)
DF = data.frame('A' = 1:3, 'B' = 1:3)
DF %>% mutate(!!aa := A*2)
```

However I failed to run this code. But I am unable to understand what is `!!` is above line? And what is significance of `:=`?

Is it similar to `DF %>% mutate('aa' := A*2)`?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In the first case, it checks for an object storing some string value i..e `aa <- "a1"`  If you want just the column to be named 'aa', you can directly use `mutate(aa = A*2)`.  i.e. it is doing some evaluation of the object passed.  Note that in `list` or vectors, you cannot directly name on the lhs with `=` with the value of an object

Comment: There is some documentation about it in `?"!!"` where it is described in detail with some examples

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Let say I have another DF as `DF1 = data.frame('1' = 1, '2' = 'BB')`. How can I use `mutate` to create a column in `DF` with name `BB` from `DF1`? I want to use `%>%` directly

Comment: You can use `DF %>% mutate(!!DF1$X2 := 'a')` in the example there is only one row for DF2.  Previously, we dealt it with `setNames` or `rename` i.e. `DF %>% mutate('a') %>% rename_with(~DF1$X2, 3)`

Comment: many thanks! I need little more generalisation. As column name, I want to pick that value from column `'2'` where `'1' == 1` in `DF1`. My actual `DF1` has many rows, so I need to pick correct row to create column in `DF`

Comment: Please check the solution posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `?"!!"`

> It is sometimes useful to force early evaluation of part of an expression before it gets fully evaluated. The tidy eval framework provides several forcing operators for different use cases. The bang-bang operator !! forces a single object.

> Unfortunately R is very strict about the kind of expressions supported on the LHS of =. This is why rlang interprets the walrus operator := as an alias of =. You can use it to supply names, e.g. a := b is equivalent to a = b.

If we need to do this on a more general case i.e. subsetting the column value from second data and create another column value as column name in first data

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
    mutate(!! (DF1 %>% 
                  filter(X1 == 1) %>%
                   pull(X2)) := 'a')
```

-output

```
  A B BB
1 1 1  a
2 2 2  a
3 3 3  a
```

#### data

```
DF1 = data.frame(X1 = 1, X2 = 'BB')
```